# Move elements on scroll vertically and horizontally (Jquery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

A friend asked me if I could help her out with a project she's working on. She wants to bring over a message and wants to do this with a website where the users can just scroll and read stuff.

Here you can check out a PDF that show what she is trying to accomplish:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bew7rw1uzjv8nwc/INFOpagina.pdf

When you start scrolling around slide 4 and 5 you should get the idea, words and images change from position when you scroll. 
So my question now is, do you guys know any Javascript or Jquery plugins that could help me achieving this? I already searched a lot on google but can't really find any stuff that's really appropriate.

Thanks, would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery Scroll Path Plugin](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/) is the perfect JQuery plugin for you.

Comment: cool trick, but you're destroying user expectations for how scrolling works :P

Comment: Can't destroy user expectations be the point? Maybe she wants something innovative, out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thanks, I've came across this side too when I googled for a solution, but I didn't think it would be good for this thing. Now I'm trying stuff out with it and it's going ok! Thanks for the help, if people still know something, do say!